# What could be a reason for `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` not to execute the exports?

Tags: bash, bashrc

the [CUDA installation tutorial](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf) tells me to add the following two lines to my `.bash_profile`.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But it does not work (TM). Even if I add these lines to `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`, I still have to enter the exports manually, for the paths to be found.

**So my question. What could be a reason for `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` not to load/execute the exports?**

Thanks!!

p.s. I ssh into the machine and it is, apart from the CUDA drive and sdk, a fresh Ubuntu 10.10 installation.

p.p.s. The fresh installation did not have a `.bash_profile` in the first place. `nano ~/.bash_profile` was empty

Comment: You wrote bash_profile and bashrc, but the files in your home directory should be .bash_profile and .bashrc (with a dot as the first letter). If that was only a typo in your post, please edit it. ~/.bash_profile is only sourced for login shells, you probably want to use ~/.bashrc. For the details please have a look [in the wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

Comment: Hi @elmicha,thank you very much for the point!!! I corrected all .bashrc and .bash_profile

Comment: Can you verify that these lines are (not) being executed? E.g. try "echo $PATH" to check the value of it. Also, read up when bash_profile and bashrc are being executed (http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile)

Comment: Hi DrSAR. I added echo $PATH to the .profile, but I could not see any effect. Should I see something when I log in?

Comment: Please be advised that setting ld_library_path in .profile, /etc/profile or /etc/environment doesn't work due to bug 366728 ( bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/366728 )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you log in graphically in Ubuntu, `.bash_profile` will not be read, but `.profile` will (sourced by sh). So if you put those exports in `.profile`, then log in again, the environment variables should be available.

Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: Would the exports also be read from the .bashrc?

Comment: Adding to .profile worked.